# Echo Wordpress admin page content?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a simple way to echo content of plugin's admin page to frontend? I would like to diplay to my subscribers opitons from another free plugin, that creates a page in admin panel. For example I have admin-page URL:

```
admin.php?page=????
```

and want to display content of it using php on normal wordpress site.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This should be in the dec of the plugin, which you do not name.

Comment: Almost certainly not, and almost certainly this would result in security vulnerabilities.  Let your users in the dashboard (as a "Subscriber") and see about exposing these admin settings in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function you made in the plugin file. If you made a separate file get the plugin directory and use `include()`.